# Do we need "mars" tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retagging

Last I checked, there's no canon with name *Mars*. Also, tag wiki indicates that it's for the planet in Sol System.

Do we need this tag? How many people browse with planet name?

Comment: There are 30 uses of the tag. All of them seem pretty mars-relevant to me.

Comment: @Richard Wow. Loved to see your diamond badge. Party?

Comment: I find it interesting that the question is not well received (+1/-7) while the answer which agrees with the question *is* (+6/-0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Do we need it? Yes.**

From the FAQ : [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other,
>   similar questions.

Are the questions that are tagged with [mars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mars) being used correctly? **Yes.** All of the questions with this tag have questions about films/books and stories that have Mars as a major theme. This includes Andy Weir's "The Martian, Total Recall, Robinson Crusoe on Mars, Kim Stanley Robinson's Mars Trilogy, etc.

> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are
>   interesting or relevant to you.

This tag is likely to be of interest to people with a special interest in stories about Mars.